# What is the mac-address of multicast (ipv6)

Tags: networking

In IPv4, ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff is broadcast address so that this frame can pass layer 2 of all machines.

In IPv6, ARP is not used but ICMPv6 is used to know mac-address by multicasting.
In this case, what is mac-address of multicasting??

If mac-address is not matched, this frame cannot pass layer 2 of destination machine.
So, I really wonder how multicast packet is passed layer 2 by not using ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff.

Answer (score 11):

Ethernet has "multicast" MAC addresses as well – any MAC address with the "group" bit set is technically a multicast address; IPv6 uses the prefix `33:33:*`, while IPv4 uses `01:00:5e:*`. There are other widely-used prefixes, see [this Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet) for details.

For IPv6 multicast addresses, the last 32 bits of the IPv6 address are OR'd with `33:33:00:00:00:00`. For example:

- The "all nodes" address `ff02::1` is converted to `33:33:00:00:00:01`.
- Neighbour solicitations for an example address `fe80::4a5d:60ff:fee8:658f` are sent to the corresponding [Solicited-Node multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solicited-node_multicast_address) address `ff02::1:ffe8:658f`, which is converted to Ethernet address `33:33:ff:e8:65:8f`.

This is described in [RFC 2624 section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2464#section-7).

Comment: As a side note, the "all nodes" address is in practice treated as broadcast, since MLD is not used for it.

Answer (score 1):

The function of arp is replace by Neighbour Solicitation in IPv6.

This article explains it best if you understand address allocation.

[Ipv6 Neighbour Solicitation](https://keepingitclassless.net/2011/10/neighbor-solicitation---ipv6s-replacement-for-arp/)

**Updated Link because of Blog Refactor:**